# Загружается ли фоновое изображение у скрытого блока?

Tags: html, css

Есть блок `.screen` со свойством `display: none`. У псевдоэлемента этого блока задано фоновое изображение.

```
.screen {
    display: none;
}

.screen::before {
    background: url("../img/bg-desktop.jpg") center top no-repeat;
}
```

Загружается ли это фоновое изображение у псевдоэлемента скрытого блока?

Comment: Учимся пользоваться инструментами вебмастера в браузере чтобы не задавать такие примитивные вопросы.

Comment: Я посмотрел во вкладке sources, но не был уверен)

Comment: @FrontEnder007 во вкладке Network смотрите.

Comment: @FrontEnder007 Там много полезных вкладок, а не только код.

Comment: Да. Можешь посмотреть через DevTools (F12)